# html datalist options disappear on whitespace

Tags: javascript, html

In input field enter `aa` and input options disappears (because in options there are no such value).
Then press keyboard button and create whitespace between `a` `a`. Get `a a`. In options such value exists, but options remains disappeared. If i type some letter, for example get `a ab`, then remove last character, then options appears.
Problem is why on whitespace options disappears? If i type letter or number, all ok. But if i type whitespace, options disappears. How to solve the problem?

Below is code and also placed https://jsfiddle.net/ohzkcmLa/

Now noticed that with Firefox all ok. But with Chrome options disappears.

Html

```
<input id ="test" type="text" list="test_list" oninput="showList(this)" placeholder="test_list" />
<datalist id="test_list">
  <option>a a</option>
  <option>a ab</option>
  <option>N Y</option>
</datalist>
```

Javascript

```
function showList(input) {
  var datalist = document.getElementById("test_list");
  if (input.value) { datalist.id = "test_list"; } 
  else { datalist.id = "test_list"; }
}

$( document ).on( 'keyup', '#test', function(element) { 
  if (element.which === 32)  { 
    this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
    document.getElementById("test").value = $(this).val() + "b";
  }
});
```

Comment: In option tag add a value attribute  eg <option value="a a">a a</option> then it will read whitespace

Comment: Added https://jsfiddle.net/ec8dL5sh/. The same problem...